# Manipular XML com PHP

Tags: php, xml

Alguém poderia me dizer como eu faço para pegar apenas o valor de nome no código abaixo.

pagina index.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://localhost/server.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resultado = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($resultado);

echo $resultado;
echo $xml->nome;
?>
```

Página server:

```
$note=<<<xml
<note>
<nome>xiro</nome>
</note>
xml;

$xml = simplexml_load_string ($note);
var_dump($xml);
```

Comment: Qual o problema que você está tendo?

Comment: Eu quero chamar o nome(xiro) na pagina index, Mas não vem. igual esse exemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipNK8Nigm08

Comment: Infelizmente não. Eu gostaria de manter a estrutura inicial com o object(SimpleXMLElement) e o  public. Dá uma olhada no vídeo que postei acima.

Comment: Se você explicar melhor o que você quer fazer, talvez haja outro modo de fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, Segui o seu exemplo mesmo e fiz algumas adaptações. creio que no vídeo o pessoal do pagseguro usa uma mascara para formatar o XML.

Comment: Ótimo. Se quiser postar uma resposta explicando como você resolveu o problema seria bom, não se esqueça de aceitar a sua resposta como aceita. Isso poderia ajudar outras pessoas com problemas semelhantes ao seu.

Comment: Cara, pelos arquivos que você passou, faça esse teste tira essas duas linhas $xml = simplexml_load_string ($note); var_dump($xml); e coloca echo $note; do arquivo server e me fala o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que passar também os parâmetros **"Pai"** do elemento.

```
$xml->note->nome;
```

Como você pode ver `<nome>` está dentro de `<note>` então você terá que setar `note` no código.

Comment: ñ deu certo Alisson

Comment: @XiroNakamura tente usar **$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resultado)** ao invez de **$xml = simplexml_load_string($resultado)** ... E para exibir, use `$xml->{'note'}->{'nome'}`

Comment: Alisson, tentei fazer assim como você disse e retornou o erro `SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in...`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Alisson.

Comment: Na documentação do PHP (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.simplexmlelement.php), quando ele faz o load, ele considera o note, como root do documento, a leitura ficaria de fato $xml->nome;

Comment: O exemplo do que disse http://ideone.com/CrBJPq

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que fazer um foreach no XML, veja é muito Simples:

```
<?php
$note=<<<xml
<note>
<nome>xiro</nome>
</note>
xml;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($note);

echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
}
```

[**Aqui tem uma demonstração**](http://ideone.com/EBTVbe)